# How to check for a specific class when checking running activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm currently using this code:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

if(taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.settings")){
    ////Do Action       
}
```

I am able to see if the current activity is com.android.settings (Android Setting Page). I am trying to replace it for a specific class file in the package com.android.setting, e.g.

```
 if(taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.settings.LocationSettings") || taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.settings/.LocationSettings")){
         ////Do Action

     }
```

My problem is that this code does not detect "LocationSettings".

I am referring to the Android source code, and Cyanogen source [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/tree/cm-10.1/src/com/android/settings).

Answer (score 0):

The class you are checking for (com.android.settings.LocationSettings) is not a subclass of Activity so it would not show up in a list of activities.

In addition, getPackageName() only returns the package. So you would need to check the class-name against getClassName() separately.